# Platform.uno newbie question, how to deploy?

Tags: wpf, web, platform

I followed the instructions to create a basic Platform.uno website, the one that says "Hello Uno Platform". I can launch it from Visual Studio and all is fine.

Next I setup a Release deploy (the .Wasm project), copied the publish folder to my website, but when I browse to https://mywebsite/publish it looks like this:

[image]

And in the browser console:

[image]

I searched for some deployment documentation, not much there. I want nothing to do with Azure (too expensive). Do I need to manually copy the missing files over manually or something? Seems like a really good idea (WPF for a website) sure would like this to work.

Update, I found the index.html has some references like this href="/package_e0758ee76e9604123d5b927a51dea84ec0dbcc71/Fonts.css" which will only work for the root folder, removing the first / helps quite a bit, lots of files loading but still some paths broken. So is there a way to configure the project to work out of a relative folder rather than only the root folder?

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the question.

Please subscribe to the following discussion:

https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/discussions/14068

Answer (score -2):

I can help you with debugging here:

1. Check Server Configuration:
   Ensure that your server is configured to serve the required file types. For a Uno Platform application, you need to make sure that .wasm files, HTML, CSS, and JavaScript files are allowed to be served
   Test Locally:
   Use it on your Localhost

Inspect Network Requests:
Check if browser is attempting to fetch the .wasm.

Clear ur cache

check srver logs

Even if you're avoiding Azure, reviewing Uno Platform's documentation on deployment might provide insights into the necessary steps and configurations for successful deployment.

By systematically checking these aspects and verifying the deployment process, you should be able to identify the cause of the "loading" issue and resolve it for your Uno Platform application.